# Adding variables to custom command,Vim editor

Tags: vim

I like to customise vim editor commands and add short readable name to it

But I want to add certain commands for ex
lineX,lineY s/^////  (commenting certain lines in the file)

I tried things like, 
command! $1,$2Comment :$1,$2s/^////

but didn't work. I am fairly new to vim. I read somewhere womething about -range, -nargs but not sure how to use them

Please help

Thank you!

Comment: Even though this is fairly easy, it isn't a good way. The comment function will only be valid for a certain file type. It is indeed possible to change the command for every file type. But instead of doing this tiresome work, you should use one of the great plugins provided. For example [vim-commentry](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary) or [nerdcommenter](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdcommenter)

Comment: Markdown is easy.

Answer (score 0):

While this isn't a full answer to your question, I think it's useful enough to provide you with a pointer to the documentation and some advice how to find it.

The two things you mentioned can be found with these commands:

- [`:help :command-range`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3acommand%2drange)
- [`:help :command-nargs`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3acommand%2dnargs)

(In order to execute a command, you type `:` to enter command-line mode. You should get a `:` in the bottom of the editor, and you can enter a command now, like "help")

In general, you should consider reading the entirety of [`:help user-commands`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#user%2dcommands), to get a good picture of how defining commands works.

In the future, if you're having difficulties figuring out the right terms to provide to `:help`, consider either using tab-completion (type `:help command` and then press the `<tab>` key to get suggestions), or use the `:helpgrep` command ([`:help :helpgrep`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/helphelp.txt.html#%3ahelpgrep)) to search for some particular text in the help files.